# Magento 2 - Custom shell command not working

Tags: magento2, cli, command

I want to execute some code using **custom command** like:

```
php bin/magento mycommand:dothis
```

To enable this command I have added this code in `di.xml`

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\Console\CommandList">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="commands" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="do_this" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\Console\Command\DoThis</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

In my .php file

```
app/code/Vendor/Module/Console/Command/DoThis.php
```

File code is:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Console\Command;

use Magento\Framework\App\State;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class DoThis extends Command
{
    /**
     * @var State
     */
    protected $appState;

    public function __construct(
        State $appState
    ) {
        $this->appState = $appState;
        parent::__construct('mycommand');
    }

    /**
     * Configure cli command.
     */
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('mycommand')
            ->setDescription('This will run do this');
    }

    /**
     * Execute cli command
     * @param InputInterface $input
     * @param OutputInterface $output
     * @return $this|int|null
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    protected function execute(
        InputInterface $input,
        OutputInterface $output
    ) {
        $this->appState->setAreaCode('adminhtml');

        //My code here

        $output->writeln('Process finished.');

        return $this;
    }
}
```

On shell, I am facing this error:

> Command "mycommand:dothis" is not defined.

Comment: Let me know if any issue still you'll face.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have one other way. You can use this code :

Create **di.xml** file and add this below code :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\Console\CommandList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="commands" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="clean_generation" xsi:type="object">RH\Commands\Model\Generation</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

Then, you need to create file for create command :

> RH\Commands\Model\Generation.php

```
<?php
namespace RH\Commands\Model;

use \Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use \Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use \Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class Generation extends Command
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('generation:clean')->setDescription('Clean Generation Folder');
        parent::configure();
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        system("rm -r generated/*");
        $output->writeln('Generation Folder Clean Successfully.');
    }
}
```

Now, execute **generation:clean** command. It will execute **rm -r generated/*** command & clear **generated** folder.

Answer (score 1):

**Please Change contructor**

> From This

```
public function __construct(
        State $appState
    ) {
        $this->appState = $appState;
        parent::__construct('mycommand');
    }
```

> To

```
public function __construct(
        State $appState
    ) {
        $this->appState = $appState;
        parent::__construct();
    }
```

Comment: Above answer worked for me, Thanks anyways you gave time answering my question. +1

Comment: I meant answer of Rohan Hapani worked for me, but still your answer is appreciated, so I gave you +1